# R calculating poisson probabilities using R

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have a problem that am trying to solve using R

Previously i had calculated the poisson distribution of x>1 with mean of 6 to be 0.983

now i would like to do the sam in R using R probability distribution function for poisson distribution.
Doing a quick research found

```
dpois()
```

Is the probability distribution function for poisson distribution

How do i calculate probability using R(dpois) of x>1 since in normal poisson i would

```
p(x>1) = 1- p(x=0) - p(x=1)
```

Comment: `1 - dpois(0, lambda) - dpois(1, lambda)` where `lambda` is the mean parameter of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: what about when i want to calculate for a larger no than 1 eg 50 how do i go about it?

Comment: Use `1 - ppois(1,6)` . The function `ppois` calculates the c. d. f. Try typing `?ppois` in the R console for help.